# A class that can only be created by another class, without using friend

Tags: c++, class

I'd like to have two non-inheritance-related and non-friends classes, class A and class B. However, i also want that class B can only be instantiated by class A, assuming that class B has a private constructor.

Is there any workaround this without having to use templates?

Comment: Why can't you use friend? Seems like that is what you want.

Comment: Make `B` a private inner class of `A`.

Comment: `friend` is your best friend in this scenario

Comment: Id like it so that class A cannot access private members of class B, yet at the same time only class A can have a class B

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks for mentioning private inner classes or otherwise known as nested classes, just read about it and it is very useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having a private constructor you could make your `class B` "private" by not placing it in any header files.

You can achieve this by using an *interface* class.

The client programmer can not instantiate the *interface* class because it is pure-virtual and it can not instantiate the implementation because it has not been declared.

The only way to instantiate it is through a factory function like this:

**The public interface:**

```
// classes.h

// pure virtual interface
struct B
{
    virtual ~B() {}

    virtual void func_1() = 0;
    virtual void func_2() = 0;
};

class A
{
public:
    // factory method
    B* create_B();
};
```

**The "private" implementation:**

```
// classes.cpp

#include "classes.h"

// the *actual* class B
class B_Implementation
: public B
{
public:
    void func_1() override
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    void func_2() override
    {
        // do stuff
    }
};

B* A::create_B()
{
    return new B_Implementation;
}
```

**The usage:**

```
int main()
{
    A a;

    auto b = std::unique_ptr<B>(a.create_B());
}
```

If this method is not appropriate to your situation then `friend` is your only friend.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful, but it also brought me another question, if you wouldn't mind of course. Can the same thing with B_Implementation be said about any classes that are only declared in a .cpp?

Comment: @DiegoLiu Yes, if there is no header file the compiler only knows about the class when it is compiling the `.cpp` file that contains it.